# String_Split Order Solution

Tags: sql-server, split, dataset, sql-order-by

**Situation:**

I have a column that I've imported into SQL Server from a flat file, now this column has a massive text string value *[no other columns have such a massive string in them]*. So what I need to do is `String_Split` the column and insert into multiple rows. However, the delimiter values are different Document File Paths which has different versions indicated at the end of the Path.

**The Split_String Query**

> ```
> select value as [New DOS file], [DOS file]
> from [Document Dataset]
> cross apply string_split([DOS file], '|')
> ```

**The issue:**

What happens is when you execute the `Split_String` query, the `[New DOS file]` value column automatically orders alphabetically. However, I need to add a `Row_Num` Grouped by `[DOS file]` but ordered by Version Number which is located near the end of the string on the `[New DOS file]`.

**Example Data as shown in excel:**

[Data Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Y9e.png)

**What I want the Data to Look like as shown in excel:**

[Data Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzgxM.png)

**Request:**

Is there a particular Syntax I can add to my `String_Split` query which accomplishes my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I posted the following question just in case anyone had a similar situation because I found the answer for it.

**Solution:**

```
select value as [New DOS file], [DOS file], A.B as Row_Num
from [Document Dataset]
cross apply (
    select value, row_number() over(order by current_timestamp) as B
    from string_split([DOS file], '|')
) A
order by value
```